# Inconsistent result when using Fortran function on numpy array with F2PY

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I am trying to understand how F2PY works. To do so, I wrote a simple Fortran function which takes an array as input and returns the sum of the elements of the array.

I wrote three different versions of the same functions, which I expect to hold the same result:

```
function rsum(arr)
real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: arr
real :: rsum
rsum=sum(arr)
end function rsum

function rsum1(arr)
real(8), dimension(:), intent(in) :: arr
real(8) :: rsum1
rsum1=sum(arr)
end function rsum1

function rsum2(arr) result(s)
real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: arr
real :: s
s=sum(arr)
end function rsum2

function rsum3(arr) result(s)
real(8), dimension(:), intent(in) :: arr
real(8) :: s
s=sum(arr)
end function rsum3
```

My python script to test these functions is the following:

```
from numpy import *
import ftest as f

a=array(range(3))

print(f.rsum(a))
print(f.rsum1(a))
print(f.rsum2(a))
print(f.rsum3(a))
```

but the result is this:

```
3.0
0.0
3.0
3.0
```

All the results are correct, except the one of `rsum1`, which is `0.0`. What I find even more strange is that `rsum3`, in which I merely change the name of the result of the function (or, at least, I think I am doing so), works perfectly!

I know this has something to do with the type conversion between Fortran and numpy, but I don't understand what the problem is.

PS: I only learned Fortran very recently.

Comment: If you are new, don't learn the bad habit of `real(8)`, where do people even pick it up? It is not in any good textbook.

Comment: `rsum1` and `rsum3` should be completely identical. But maybe f2py interprets one of the wrong.

Comment: I can replicate it. When I call them in a Fortran subroutine which is called from f2py the result is correct. But even in Python the reported signature of the `f.*` functions is correct.

Comment: @VladimirF Regarding the notation real(8), someone taught it to me. Why is it so bad? Also, I don't understand: are you getting my same error when running the script?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error. Real(8) is not portable, it will not compile with some compilers. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201703142319329773677 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/856243/721644

Comment: I have experimented with f2py a few times and as I recall f2py doesn't play great with assumed shape arrays. Maybe pass the size of the array to the function and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Short answer* and workaround

The root cause of the problem is related the use of assumed-shape dummy arguments (i.e. `arr`) in your functions. Fortran requires such functions to have explicit interfaces. @VladimirF gave an excellent answer to your (related?) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42767455/3967096) about just that, indicating that the preferred solution is to put the functions in a module. Assuming your code listing with functions is saved in a file called `funcs.f90`, you can simply put them into a module, e.g. called `mod_funcs.f90`, like so:

```
module mod_funcs
    implicit none
    contains
        include "funcs.f90"
end module mod_funcs
```

Wrap this with F2PY `python -m numpy.f2py -m ftest -c mod_funcs.f90`, update the import statement in your python test script to `from ftest import mod_funcs as f` and then run it to get the expected result:

```
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
```

### The longer answer and explanation

Fortran `function`s are wrapped in `subroutine`s by F2PY. In order to support assumed-shape arrays in a Fortran standard compliant way, the F2PY created subroutine wrappers contain `interface`s for user defined functions with assumed-shape dummy arguments. You can have a look at these wrappers by specifying a build directory with a `--build-dir` flag when wrapping with F2PY, e.g. like this:

```
python -m numpy.f2py --build-dir .\build -m ftest -c funcs.f90
```

Looking at the wrapper that is created for the *problematic* function `rsum1` is revealing (I'm copying verbatim from `ftest-f2pywrappers.f` keeping F2PY's indentation):

```
subroutine f2pywraprsum1 (rsum1f2pywrap, arr, f2py_arr_d0)
integer f2py_arr_d0
real(8) arr(f2py_arr_d0)
real(8) rsum1f2pywrap
interface
function rsum1(arr) 
    real(8), dimension(:),intent(in) :: arr
end function rsum1
end interface
rsum1f2pywrap = rsum1(arr)
end
```

Note that due to [implicit data typing rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007365fbc/index.html), the `interface` for `rsum1` implies a function with `real` data type, **not** `real(8)` as intended - so there is a data type mismatch in the interface! This explains why the seemingly identical function with an explicit `result` statement (`rsum3`) returns the correct result in your original example, its result has the correct data type. By good fortune in naming your functions, `rsum` has the correct interface. If you change `rsum`'s name to e.g. `isum`, implicit data typing rules in its F2PY subroutine wrapper interface will imply that it has an `integer` result, and you will get the following output from your (modified to reflect the name change from `fsum` to `isum`) python script:

```
0.0
0.0
3.0
3.0
```

So to me it appears as if there may be a bug in how F2PY creates interfaces for functions with assumed-shape dummy arguments (which can be bypassed by putting those functions into a module directly, or by explicitly declaring return value of the function using `result`).

For completeness, I was using `Python 3.6.3 :: Intel Corporation`, with `NumPy 1.14.3`, and `GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.2.0`.