# Required interface for passing assumed shape array is missing from original source

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I'm having a problem compiling a Fortran program using Visual Studio and Intel Parallel Studio, it's returning the following error:

error #7978: Required interface for passing assumed shape array is missing from original source.

The call is:

```
Call MontaPrecondicionadorJacob (el,cone,ke,PP)
```

The subroutine is:

```
subroutine MontaPrecondicionadorJacob (el,cone,ke,PP)
implicit none
!   Parâmetros da subroutina
!      
integer,intent(in):: el             !
integer,intent(in):: cone(:,:)      !
real(8),intent(in):: ke(:,:)        !
real(8),intent(out):: PP(:)         !
!
!   Variáveis internas
!
integer:: no
integer:: gl
!
do no=1,20
    do gl=1,3              
        PP((cone(el,no)-1)*3+gl)=PP((cone(el,no)-1)*3+gl)+ke((no-1)*3+gl,(no-1)*3+gl)                        
    end do
end do
end subroutine
```

Comment: You'll almost certainly find the answer to the question you haven't asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766530/procedure-with-assumed-shape-dummy-argument-must-have-an-explicit-interface

Comment: And also https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/01/05/doctor-fortran-gets-explicit-again